# Gradle Sync Failed, no route to host and connection times out

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've been trying to install android studio on my pc, but the Gradle isn't getting synced. On connecting my device with wifi, it shows the error No route to host:Connect and with LAN it shows Connection timed out:Connect

Comment: Can you please share the content of your build.gradle file? or screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. I ran a troubleshooting through the control panel on my wifi and it showed that the windows was not able to identify the proxy settings, so I went to the internet explorer and in it's advanced settings unchecked the box which said Use Proxy Server. My Android studio is working fine now. Thank You!